# Multiple conditions under IF in transact SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to use 'and' in an If condition as follows:

```
Begin
If condition1 and condition2 
then begin result1 
end else begin result2;
End;
end;
```

what is wrong in the statement. Could anybody help in thei matter? Thanks!

Comment: The pseudo-code is correct, however I'm guessing your actual code does have a problem, but since you only posted pseudo-code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Does the word then exist in your actual code? if so get rid of it. if conditions should only contain if begin and end. Your pseudo-code wont even compile

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess, lose the 'then' (SFrejofsky's comment), and lose the first ; which is inside of a begin..end block.

Also if there is only executable line in a block then begin..end is not needed, so your code should look like this

```
If condition1 and condition2 
  result1 
else 
  result2
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `THEN`. Example

```
DECLARE @variable INT = 0
DECLARE @variable2 INT = 10

IF @variable > 0 AND @variable2 > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Condition was met'

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Condition was not met'

END
```

If you want to chain `IFs`:

```
DECLARE @variable INT = 0
DECLARE @variable2 INT = 10

IF @variable > 0 AND @variable2 > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Condition 1 was met'

END
ELSE IF @variable = 0 AND @variable2 > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Condition 2 was met'

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT 'No condition was met'

END
```

Also, you can avoid the `BEGIN` ... `END` if you just need one statement, but it can be tricky to read if expressions are long.

```
DECLARE @variable INT = 0
DECLARE @variable2 INT = 10

IF @variable > 0 AND @variable2 > 0
    SELECT 'Condition was met'
ELSE
    SELECT 'Condition was not met'
```

Answer (score -1):

`Begin
If condition1 and condition2 
  result1 
else 
  result2
END`